# Vertical Spacing After NewEnvironment Definition

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, environments

How can I modify this,

```
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{\begin{mdframed}\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}\end{mdframed}}
```

so that a newline (vertical space) is inserted after the word "Definition"? I want the content of my definition(s) to start below it.

Comment: Why are you working with a `trivlist` here? What is your goal in the first place? There might be a much simpler solution.

Comment: By the way, there are theorem related packages that allow you to define *Definition* environments pretty easily.

Comment: @Johannes_B Its just the look of what it produces. I am really open to change it. What I have above is just from an online source.

Comment: I am interested, do you have a link available?

Comment: @Johannes_B No, sorry. I didn't save it. I am interested in something that is boxed off and had "Definition" in bold, and a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitions are usually made with a theorem package like `amsthm`. On the other hand, if you are not sure if you want some more fancy stuff later on, i would start with something based on `tcolorbox`. The example shows the default box, it can be customized in various ways, to look more simple or to look even much more *fancy*.

[image: phattyDefinitionEnvironment]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{definition}{title=Definition,}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{phatty}{2ex}{2ex}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{phatty}
\newtheorem*{pht}{Phatty}
\surroundwithmdframed{pht}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
    \blindtext
\end{definition}
\begin{pht}
    \blindtext
\end{pht}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will make some sweet looking definitions, now.